# How to empty a file in fish?

Tags: fish

In **bash** shell scripting, I would typically run `:> file` to empty a file.

Now using fish, things are slightly different and the above command doesn't work.

What is fish equivalent?

Comment: I gave you a +1 because this is the first time I heard of fish.

Comment: ;-) it's a really nice unix shell - you should give it a try

Comment: in fish 3 `:>file` works nice.

Answer (score 21):

Although it's not as short as `:`, `true` is a command that will work everywhere and produces no output:

```
true > file
```

Comment: This should be the top answer!

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way that will be work in both Fish and Bash is to do `echo "" > file`

EDIT: Commenter was absolutely right `echo "" > file` produces a file with a newline, the correct command I was thinking of to create an **empty** file is `cat /dev/null > file`.

Comment: That will actually create a file with a newline character in it.

Comment: `echo -n > file` will avoid the newline. This is more efficient than cat, because it does not require invoking any external commands.

Comment: I kind of like true > file better

Comment: in `bash` I simply write `>file`

Answer (score 0):

There is, and always was the magic method called `touch` which set change time to actual or create non-existent file. For compatiblity I suggest you to use this way in all scripts that you write (even if you write bash code).

Comment: That won't truncate an existing file.

Comment: Yep. But I think that you want to create empty file. If you want to set empty file thn you should use @Paul Hamilton answer with `-n` flag or `rm file; and touch file`.